# Using display: table to center a modal on the page?

Tags: html, css

I tried this which I found as a suggestion here on SO:

```
 <div style="display:table; width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
            <div id="modal" style="width: 10rem; height: 10rem;">
                xxx
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

This does not seem to center the modal at all. Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Update:  Horizontal position is now fixed by using display: inline-block for the id modal

Comment: text-align:center only works for inline content. So div#modal has to be display:inline-block;

Comment: Thanks. This corrected the horizontal centering. But vertically it's still not in the middle. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `display: inline-block;` to the div with id `modal`.

```
<div style="display:table; width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center; ">
            <div id="modal" style="width: 10rem; height: 10rem; display: inline-block;">
                xxx
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

And apply this CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

See this working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8uhbh6jz/

Answer (score 0):

Add display:table-cell to modal div

```
 <div style="display:table; width: 100%; height: 100%">
    <div style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;">
        <div id="modal" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; width: 10rem; height: 10rem;">
            xxx
        </div>
    </div>
```